# How to remove multiple white spaces or \t from an item of a list in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to remove extra balnks and characters from elements of my list but i couldnt accomplish that though i tried split(), strip() and the code below.How can I do it?

what i tried is;

```
import re

movie_list=["   The Room"," Boyhood","\t\tThe Help"]


for i in movie_list:
    i=re.sub('[ \t]+' , ' ',i)
print(movie_list)
```

Comment: All you're doing in that `for` loop is rebinding the variable `i`; you're not changing the list. To do that, you'll need to index the list. You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the indices (along with the list members).

Comment: @glibdud yes you are right. it worked now! thanks..

Answer (score 2):

If you want to strip white spaces from beginning and end:

```
[m.strip() for m in movie_list]
```

It gives:

```
['The Room', 'Boyhood', 'The Help']
```

If you want to remove repeated white spaces:

```
import re
[re.sub(r'[ \t]+', '', m) for m in movie_list]
```

You can also combine both:

```
import re
[re.sub(r'[ \t]+', '', m.strip()) for m in movie_list]
```

In your example, pay attention to the fact that `i=re.sub('[ \t]+' , ' ',i)` is redefining variable `i` but *not* modifying your list. To actually make changes to the list, you can either

```
for index, value in enumerate(movie_list):
    movie_list[index] = some_function(value)
```

or redefine `movie_list`:

```
movie_list = [some_function(m) for m in movie_list]
```